# FastAPI Test Case not running

Tags: python-3.x, api, unit-testing, fastapi

I am trying to run FastAPI test case's but it is showing - **no tests ran**

**This is Main.py -**

```
import psycopg2
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, HTTPException
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

class User(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int

def get_db_connection():
    connection = psycopg2.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="********",
        password="********",
        database="user"
    )

    return connection

# Create a user
@app.post("/users")
def create_user(user: User, db_conn = Depends(get_db_connection)):
    cursor = db_conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        "INSERT INTO users (name, age) VALUES (%s, %s)",
        (user.name, user.age)
    )

    db_conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    return {"id": cursor.lastrowid, "name": user.name, "age": user.age}



# Read a user
@app.get("/users/{user_id}")
def read_user(user_id: int, db_conn = Depends(get_db_connection)):
    cursor = db_conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        "SELECT id, name, age FROM users WHERE id=%s",
        (user_id,)
    )

    user = cursor.fetchone()
    cursor.close()
    if user is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="User not found")
    return {"id": user[0], "name": user[1], "age": user[2]}



@app.put("/users/{user_id}")
def update_user(user_id: int, user: User, db_conn = Depends(get_db_connection)):
    cursor = db_conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        "UPDATE users SET name=%s, age=%s WHERE id=%s",
        (user.name, user.age, user_id)
    )

    db_conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    return {"id": user_id, "name": user.name, "age": user.age}

@app.delete("/users/{user_id}")
def delete_user(user_id: int, db_conn = Depends(get_db_connection)):
    cursor = db_conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        "DELETE FROM users WHERE id=%s",
        (user_id,)
    )
    db_conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    return {"message": "user deleted"}
```

**This is unit_test.py**

```
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from main import app

client = TestClient(app=app)

def test_create_user():
    data = {"name": "John", "age": 30}
    response = client.post("/users")
    assert response.status_code == 201
    assert response.json() == {"id": 1, "name": "John", "age": 30}

def test_read_user():
    response = client.get("/users/1")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == {"id": 1, "name": "John", "age": 30}

def test_read_non_existent_user():
    response = client.get("/users/2")
    assert response.status_code == 404

def test_update_user():
    data = {"name": "Jane", "age": 35}
    response = client.put("/users/1")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == {"id": 1, "name": "Jane", "age": 35}

def test_delete_user():
    response = client.delete("/users/1")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == {"message": "user deleted"}
```

I tried to run the file but it is showing no tests ran and collected 0 items. I used `pytest` command to run this test inside the same directory where my 2 files are present.

**Here the problem is no test case is collecting and running. Where did I do wrong here?**

Comment: First of all: did you install httpx as they require in FastAPI docs? See [link](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/testing/)

Comment: @enslaved_programmer yes i have insalled httpx and i did everything that is present in FastAPI docs

Comment: Try rename unit_test.py to test_unit.py

Comment: What is the directory tree structure exactly? How do you run pytest?

Comment: please give us directory tree structure.
you should use "test' word in your directory and file name of test.

Comment: First your test file is wrongly named, it should be `test_unit.py` and not `unit_test.py` the file should start with `test`. Second you should show how you are running your tests with pytest including the directory structure.

Comment: Thank you far your valuable comments after changing the file name it is working.